# Motion tracking portrait video

Tags: tracking

I need a little help, when I upload a portrait video in blender it flips into landscape, how do I make it into portrait
It automatically flip my portrait video into landscape. Really need help

Comment: Those videos are landscape originaly (they have bigger width than height in their properties) but have an information somewhere which makes the player rotate them by 90° (I can't find this info in the properties). Probably the most simple solution if you convert them before adding to Blender. (You can rotate and resize in the Video Sequence Editor and render, so you don't need external software).